# Regex pattern to match where my code breaks

Tags: regex

I have the following values that I want to place into a mysql db

The pattern should look as follows, I need a regex to make sure that the pattern is always as follows:

```
('', '', '', '', '')
```

In some rare execution of my code, I hower get the following output where one of the apostrophes disapear. it dissapears every now and then on the 4th record. like in the code below where I placed the `*`

```
('1', '2576', '1', '*, 'y')
```

anyideas to solve this will be welcomed!

This should be able to match one of the times the code breaks

```
string.replace(/, \',/ig, ', \'\',');
```

how would I do it if it is like this

```
('1', '2576', '1', 'where I have text here and it breaks at the end*, 'y')
```

I am using javascript and asp

I think the solution would be something like this

`string.replace(/, \'[a-zA-Z0-9],/ig, ', \'\',');`  but not exactly sure how to write it

This is almost the solution that I am looking for...

```
string.replace(/[a-zA-Z0-9], \'/ig, '\', \'');
```

this code however replaces the last letter of the text with the `', '` so if the text inside the string is `'approved, '` it will replace the `'approve', '` and cut off the letter `d`

I know there is a way that you can reference it not to remove the last letter but not sure how to do it

Comment: In order to answer your question correctly, please write what is your RDBMS and what programming language you use to build queries.

Comment: I am using javascript and asp

Comment: Couldn't you just count the number of apostrophes in your text? Or do you need to handle escaped apostrophes, too?

Comment: I don't think you should look for a way how to postprocess your SQL, you'd better look for a bug where you build it.

Comment: I am placing escaped aphostrophys into the code with a \' infront of it... I think it should be something like 
string.replace(/, \'[a-zA-Z0-9],/ig, ', \'\',');

Comment: codeholic I know exactly where it is making the error - and it is sort of expected... but will be harder to fix it there than to handle it like the way I am proposing.

Comment: @Gerald, whatever you do decide to do, even if its harder to fix the error where it occurs, its always better to fix the error where it happens then try to work around it.

Comment: You cannot be sure, that that kind of postprocessing catches all SQL injections. Moreover, this can just corrupt your data. What's the problem where you build your query? I believe it should be an error in the quoting function. What's hard to fix it?

Comment: it is a script that takes 200 articles and compare 200 articles with each other for duplication - it does like 40 000 comparisons with each other in a single script... then something happens somewhere with the split function and it does not assign the ' correctly to the 4 th record... after it has run the tests, it creates an insert statement to place all the duplicates into my db... I suspect it is easier to handle the missing ' instead of changing the coding... as it sorts of happens at more or less the same time, and the regex acts like a sort of validation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  It matches when all but the last field is missing the '

```
\('.*?'\)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression, would be something like this:

```
^\('.*?',\ '.*?',\ '.*?',\ '.*?',\ '.*?'\)$
```

you could check if your string matchs in ASP.net with some code similar to this:

```
   Match m = Regex.Match(inputString, @"^\('.*?',\ '.*?',\ '.*?',\ '.*?',\ '.*?'\)$");
   if (!m.Success)
   {
         //some fix logic here
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Sniper, I am using ASP classic